# Generating an array of random numbers without duplicates

Tags: java, random, duplicates

I have been banging my head for two days now trying to make sure the random generator method won't generate a duplicate. This I had to do with loops only without importing any libraries. I have come to this solution, will this code generate a duplicate on the long run? If yes please help.

```
int[] vargu1 = new int[5];

for (int i = 0; i < vargu1.length; i++) {
    int numriSekret = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    vargu1[i] = numriSekret;
}

System.out.println(vargu1[i]);
System.out.println();

for (int i = 0; i < vargu1.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (vargu1[i] == vargu1[j]) {
            vargu1[i]++;
        }
        System.out.println(vargu1[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: if it's not able to generate duplicates, it's no longer a 'random generator', so what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Stultuske I am trying to make sure that the random method won't give me the same number twice.

Comment: If you think you need "random numbers without duplicates", then you don't understand the problem. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Since you said without any libraries you could reimplement the [Collections.shuffle(...)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.shuffle%28java.util.List%2Cjava.util.Random%29) method for arrays.

```
int [] randoms = new int[5];

// creating an array containing the numbers 1-10
int [] shuffleArray = new int[10];
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    shuffleArray[i-1] = i;
}

// shuffling that array
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int j = random.nextInt(10);
    int tmp = shuffleArray[i];
    shuffleArray[i] = shuffleArray[j];
    shuffleArray[j] = tmp;
}

// assigning the first 5 values to the random array
for (int i = 0; i < randoms.length; i++) {
    randoms[i] = shuffleArray[i];
}
```

Although i have to remark that `Random` needs an import too (needs a library too)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand what you are doing, a better way would/could be:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for ( int i = 0; i < expectedNumberOfUniques; i++){
  Integer a = generateRandom();
  while ( myList.contains(a)){
    a = generateRandom();
  }
  myList.add(a);
}
```

A few remarks, though: the more elements in myList, the less efficiënt it might be less efficiënt.

But: as soon as you limit it to 'no duplicates allowed', we are no longer talking about 'random' numbers.

Comment: I know it won't be called a random if I limit it, but I have to make sure to not generate the same number twice. I have to do this without importing any libraries.